# iterating through a list of printf

Tags: iteration

I have a list of prinf functions and i want to know how to iterate through them.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void N()
{
    int count;
    count += count;
}

int main()

{
   int pfReturnCount = 0;

   pfReturnCount = printf("#####.00000000000.......00000...00000#### \n");
   pfReturnCount = printf("#####..000.....000......000000...000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount = printf("#####..000.....000......000.000..000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount = printf("#####..0000000000.......000..000.000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount = printf("#####..000.....000......000...000000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount = printf("#####..000.....000......000....00000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount = printf("#####.00000000000......00000...00000.#### \n");

   N(pfReturnCount);
   printf("data value after calling the N funtion is %d\n",pfReturnCount);

   return (0);
}
```

I got it to give me the value of the first printf but i don't know how to iterate through the whole list so i can sum up the total number of characters i have in all the printf functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace = with +=

```
#include <stdio.h>


void N()
{
    int count;
    count += count;
}

int main()

{
   int pfReturnCount = 0;

   pfReturnCount += printf("#####.00000000000.......00000...00000#### \n");
   pfReturnCount += printf("#####..000.....000......000000...000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount += printf("#####..000.....000......000.000..000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount += printf("#####..0000000000.......000..000.000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount += printf("#####..000.....000......000...000000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount += printf("#####..000.....000......000....00000.#### \n");
   pfReturnCount += printf("#####.00000000000......00000...00000.#### \n");

   N(pfReturnCount);
   printf("data value after calling the N funtion is %d\n",pfReturnCount);

   return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push each line to an array of strings and then simply get the length of each element in the array.